# Constructor with default arguments can not be called when inherited

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, inherited-constructors

Please take a look at the code:

```
struct X {};

struct Foo {
    Foo (int n = {}, int p = {}) {}
};

struct Boo : Foo {
    using Foo::Foo;

    Boo (X n) {}
};
```

And usage:

```
Boo boo1;
```

Error message (GCC 5.2.1):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Boo::Boo()’
```

I know that `Boo` has no default constructor, but constructor of `Foo` has been inherited and can not be called this way. Why? Does it mean that inherited constructor can only by called if derived class has no constructor (or default one)?